# Fedora 33: WiFi Hotspot not activating, driver saying that doesn't support AP but adapter actually does

Tags: networkmanager, wifi-hotspot

I have fresh install of Fedora 33 (upgraded from Fedora 32) and decided to move to the modern NetworkManager's managed wifi setup. I have successfully performed some pre-required steps like creation of connection, adding WPA-PSK security, and so on. But when I try to turn on WiFi Hotspot it says that "Connection activation failed".

Well, here is my stuff:

lspci:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

nmcli con show:

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
CAR HotSpot         a00c1f40-956a-4a05-8188-29f8011729c1  wifi      wlp2s0
Wired connection 1  3f0c71e5-1001-37ce-9db2-22dd1a43c36b  ethernet  eno1
virbr0              ea74cc68-fe37-4172-9b89-b9f95a03d367  bridge    virbr0
```

CAR HotSpot is grayed out.

```
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5901] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'CAR HotSpot' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5902] Config: added 'ssid' value 'CAR'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'mode' value '2'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'frequency' value '2412'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'freq_list' value '2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'proto' value 'RSN'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'pairwise' value 'CCMP'
Oct 31 16:08:24 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153304.5903] Config: added 'group' value 'CCMP'
Oct 31 16:08:49 car NetworkManager[1074]: <warn>  [1604153329.6344] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Hotspot network creation took too long, failing activation
Oct 31 16:08:49 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153329.6345] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 31 16:08:49 car NetworkManager[1074]: <warn>  [1604153329.6376] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'CAR HotSpot'
Oct 31 16:08:49 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153329.6378] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 31 16:08:49 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153329.6385] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6723] policy: auto-activating connection 'CAR HotSpot' (a00c1f40-956a-4a05-8188-29f8011729c1)
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6730] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'CAR HotSpot' (a00c1f40-956a-4a05-8188-29f8011729c1)
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6732] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6771] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6775] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'CAR HotSpot' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6775] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6822] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6832] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6836] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'CAR HotSpot' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6837] Config: added 'ssid' value 'CAR'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6837] Config: added 'mode' value '2'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6838] Config: added 'frequency' value '2412'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6838] Config: added 'freq_list' value '2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6838] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6838] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6838] Config: added 'proto' value 'RSN'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6838] Config: added 'pairwise' value 'CCMP'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6838] Config: added 'group' value 'CCMP'
Oct 31 16:08:50 car NetworkManager[1074]: <info>  [1604153330.6944] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
```

/var/log/wpa_supplicant.log

```
wlp2s0: Driver does not support AP mode
wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
```

Okay, what I have here (iw list):

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
```

So, what can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was in incorrect driver used in wpa_supplicant. Here is an excerpt from the **/etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant**:

Before:

```
DRIVERS="-D wext"
```

After:

```
DRIVERS="-D nl80211"
```

**/var/log/wpa_supplicant.log**:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
wlp2s0: Could not read SSID from driver
Note: nl80211 driver interface is not designed to be used with ap_scan=2; this can result in connection failures
Using interface wlp2s0 with hwaddr d0:57:7b:85:46:5c and ssid "CAR"
wlp2s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlp2s0: AP-ENABLED
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to d0:57:7b:85:46:5c completed [id=1 id_str=]
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95
wlp2s0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 9c:fc:e8:f3:51:4c
wlp2s0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 9c:fc:e8:f3:51:4c
```